# generating subscription object for push notification, using public wifi

Tags: javascript, networking, browser, push-notification, service-worker

I'm currently working on applying service worker api to my react app such as push notification api to draw the user's attentions regardless if they're on the web site or not.

while coding for that, I found some problem with generating subscription using public wifi and safari. I have tested the code that generates subscription obj using

`const pushManager = await window.pushManager; const subscription = await pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true, applicationServerKey: publicVapidKey });`

like this in react. it worked in some network environment except for some certain public wifi connection with safari. but with the same wifi, Google chrome was successfully generating the subscription object while safari failed. but with exactly the same code, it smoothly worked in my home network.

what's the problem?

is there any limitation of push notification api and network enviorment that I don't know?

I tried to test the code in 3 different place, and every time when I was using public wifi and safari, it wasn't able to show me the subscription object.